# How can i prevent user go to another link

Tags: jquery, properties, default

Its my HTML code for a image that is link to the another page.

```
<a href="#" class="dead_prfile_step_next ADInNext">
<img alt="next" src="/Content/DesignFiles/@Html.R(VirtualPath, "dead_profile_free_buttons_next.png")"  />
</a>
```

This is my jquery function for going to next page there is a DDL for months. In that DDL if user selects the previous month than this image link should not work. Otherwise i should work, i know here must be implement a if condition but how can i disable the link for a specific conditions?

```
$('.ADInNext').click(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("en-US") > -1) {
            $('.txtDatePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    var ddlSelectedPaper = $('#addNewspaperGroup_1 .ddlclassNewpaper option:selected').val();
                    checkPaperAvailability(dateText, ddlSelectedPaper, 1);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.txtDatePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    var ddlSelectedPaper = $('#addNewspaperGroup_1 .ddlclassNewpaper option:selected').val();
                    checkPaperAvailability(dateText, ddlSelectedPaper, 1);
                }
            });
        }
        $('.ui-helper-hidden-accessible').css('left', '0px');
        var OtherOpeningLine = $.trim($("#OtherOpeningLine").val());
        var OtherSigned = $.trim($("#OtherSigned").val());
        var OtherShiva = $.trim($("#OtherShiva").val())
        var OtherSecondline = $.trim($("#OtherSecondLine").val())
        if ($("#OpeningLine option:selected").val() == "") {

            $("#lblOpeningLine").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Opening Line")');
            return false;
        }
        if ('@AdType' == "Obituary") {
            if ($("#SecondLine option:selected").val() == "") {

                $("#lblSecondLine").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Second Line")');
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#SecondLine option:selected").val() == "0") {
                if (OtherSecondline == "") {
                    $("#lblSecondLine").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Opening Line")');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($("#Signed option:selected").val() == "") {

            $("#lblSigned").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Signed")');
            return false;
        }
        if ($("#OpeningLine option:selected").val() == "0") {
            if (OtherOpeningLine == "") {
                $("#lblOpeningLine").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Opening Line")');
                return false;
            }
        }

        //To validate if Funeral date is less than current date.
        ValidatefuneralDate()

        if ($("#Signed option:selected").val() == "0") {

            if (OtherSigned == "") {
                $("#lblSigned").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "Select Signed")');
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($("#Shiva option:selected").val() == "0") {
            if (OtherShiva == "") {
                $("#lblShiva").html('@Html.R(VirtualPath, "ShivaRequired")');
                return false;
            }
        }

        var valid = true;
        $('.tab1 input').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).valid() == 0) valid = false;
        });
        if (valid == true) {
            $('.dead_prfile_tab ').addClass("dn");
            $('.tab2').removeClass("dn");
            return false;
        }
        else return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this based on your conditions.

```
$('.ADInNext').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JUST put the if condition after click function of .AdInNext and then check whether if month chosen by a user is greater than equal to the current month. if it is true then go to next link otherwise go to the else part where i i am returning false.

```
 $('.ADInNext').click(function () {
    if ($('#Month option:selected').val() >= month) {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("en-US") > -1) {
            $('.txtDatePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    var ddlSelectedPaper = $('#addNewspaperGroup_1 .ddlclassNewpaper option:selected').val();
                    checkPaperAvailability(dateText, ddlSelectedPaper, 1);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $('.txtDatePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    var ddlSelectedPaper = $('#addNewspaperGroup_1 .ddlclassNewpaper option:selected').val();
                    checkPaperAvailability(dateText, ddlSelectedPaper, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        $('.ADInNext').click(function () { });
        return false;
    }
```